# Sprite Kit: changing zRotation in DidBeginContact

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

```
SKSpriteNode *_node;

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
     _node.alpha = 0.5; //this works
     _node.zRotation = 0.5; // this doesn't work
}
```

Any ideas why `zRotation` doesn't work? I tried doing `NSLog` and it gives the right `zRotation` but the screen is not showing.

Comment: What do you mean "the screen is not showing"? What do you expect to get?

Comment: I expect to see _node do a rotation but it doesn't rotate.

Comment: May be `zRotation` is already set to `0.5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at what the runloop looks like for SpriteKit. Nothing is drawn until after physics are simulated. So even though you are setting the zRotation manually it is probably overridden by the physicsBody and set to its own value. Try putting an NSLog into the -didSimulatePhysics method to get the zRotation before render. I would try moving your zRotation setter to -didSimulatePhysics.

The order of operations is

```
-update:
action evaluation
-didEvaluateActions
run physics
-didSimulatePhysics
render the scene
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html

Comment: I'm trying to make a one directional lever that turns in only one direction. So if the lever is hit in another direction, it shouldn't move. I've tried at didEvaluateActions and didSimulatePhysics but it doesn't work. The lever will still move then stop.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea that may work: setup the lever as a contact object so you'll get a callback when the lever is hit. Get the position of the object colliding with the lever. If the object is colliding on the wrong side/direction then try setting `level.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;` otherwise set it to yes. You could also try forcing the zRotation here if that doesn't work.

Comment: I did that and it'll move a little first. Am I right to say if I make it as a contact object I have to set delegate to this object and I can only have ONE such object detecting touches? Another thing is forcing zRotation at DidBeginContact have no effect. I just wonder why this is so even though forcing alpha works.

Comment: So far the best I can achieve is that there will be a bounce at the non rotating direction. I set the present zRotation at DidBeginContact and pass the parameter at DiDEvaluateActions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, when setting zRotation and position for SKSpriteNode with physicsBody didn't have any effect, while with physicsBody set to nil everything was ok.
As joshd supposed physicsBody's simulation somehow overrides these values after they are set manually. So a workaround for me was to remove body temporarily, then orient and position the sprite, then recreate physics body from scratch or from a stored property

```
storedPhysicsBody = physicsBody
physicsBody = nil
position = newPosition
zRotation = newZRotation
physicsBody = storedPhysicsBody
```