# Super weird spritekit bug

Tags: ios, debugging, swift, sprite-kit

**Okay I've reproduced this in a simple project and want to see if anyone can figure this out.**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4kzFbLmJr19QzFEa3NEZERLVnc/view?usp=sharing

**tap to send yellow squares at the red square causing a collision.  The red square SHOULD rotate but it doesnt.  Go into didBeginContact, and uncomment the code noted, and you will see it rotate.  super weird.**

I've hit a bug that has me stumped.  I really cant figure this one out.  I've tried all the obvious things, and simplified it down pretty far.

When I try to rotate my sprite inside of didBeginContact I have to do so inside of an action for it to work.  Look at the following example:

**doesnt work**

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    println(self.hyperShip.zRotation)  // prints 0 (next time STILL zero, NO PLACE IS THIS RESET)
    self.hyperShip.zRotation = 1
    println(self.hyperShip.zRotation)  // prints 1
}
```

if i run the code in an action

**works**

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    println(self.hyperShip.zRotation)  // first time 0, thereafter 1
    self.runAction(SKAction.runBlock({
        self.hyperShip.zRotation = 1
    }))
    println(self.hyperShip.zRotation) // first time 0, thereafter 1
}
```

what is the difference?  why would this behave any differently.  it's so freaking weird.  I can't see why they behave any differently.

if I trigger this code in my update or wherever else it works just fine the normal way

hypership is a subclass of another subclass of skspritenode (baseship).. not sure that why that'd make a difference, but i figured id include that detail

**EDIT: how I assign hypership**

I assign it at the top of hyperscene as a property

```
let hyperShip: HyperShip = HyperShip()
```

some setup in my scenes init

```
hyperShip.lives = self.lives
self.indicators.livesDisplay.text = "\(hyperShip.lives)"
hyperShip.addToParent(gameLayer)
```

addToParent function

```
override func addToParent(parentNode: SKNode){
    super.addToParent(parentNode)
    parentNode.addChild(self)
    self.hyperScene = parentNode.scene as HyperScene


    self.shipTrail.zPosition = -1
    self.shipTrail.position = CGPoint(x: convertNum(-8), y: 0)
    self.addChild(self.shipTrail)

    self.hyperTrail.targetNode = self.hyperScene.starFieldFG.node
    self.addChild(self.hyperTrail)

}
```

addToParent function in baseShip

```
func addToParent(parentNode: SKNode){
    self.baseScene = parentNode.scene as BaseScene
}
```

hypership's init

```
override init(){
    super.init()
}
```

baseship's init

```
override init() {
    let texture = shipAtlas.textureNamed("ship")
    super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: texture.size())

    self.color = SKColor.grayColor()
    self.zPosition = 1
}
```

I could copy paste more code, related to hyperships functionality, but I feel like its unrelated code.  It's a fairly simple class.

Comment: do you perhaps change the value of self.hyperShip at any time, so that its properties are set on different instances depending on when the code executes? Post the code related to assigning hyperShip.

Comment: I'm going to create a new simple project and see if I run into this bug.  If I do, I'll post that project so you guys can see.

Comment: I've reproduced this will the simple possible project. I've posted the link at the top of my question.

Comment: hmmm this person had same problem http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10462

Comment: it seems like it has to do with the render loop and redrawing the sprite.. specifics here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324728/sprite-kit-changing-zrotation-in-didbegincontact   pretty confusing stuff

Comment: yes but physics should not change zPosition, only zRotation, so i don't think this issue applies here but it's worth considering it and trying a workaround (ie change zPosition in didSimulatePhysics) to be sure